# Is there any valid method to duplicate sockaddr?

Tags: c++

Lets assume that I have used `getaddrinfo` and resolved an address successfully:

```
//...
s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result);
if (s != 0)
    return -1;

if (result != nullptr) {
    // ....
}

freeaddrinfo(result);
```

in this case, `result->ai_addr` and `result->ai_addrlen` refer to a `sockaddr` structure and its size(which is based on its type). Now assume that we want to duplicate this `sockaddr` in C++. What is the best valid approach to do so? I wrote this code, but I'm not sure if it is UB-free:

```
auto deleter = [](void* buf) { if (buf) free(buf); };

auto buf = malloc(result->ai_addrlen); 
if (buf) {
    memcpy(buf, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
}

std::unique_ptr<sockaddr, decltype(deleter)> myptr(static_cast<sockaddr*>(buf), deleter);
```

Is this a valid C++ code?

Comment: The biggest downside to doing this is you don't retain the *length* of the address, which is nearly always needed when using a generic `sockaddr *` in some socket api context. For example, `connect` and `bind` ; both you provide the socket address *and* length. If you want to make an addr wrapper, I'd suggest a formal object hosting an RAII container (eg. `std::vector<uint8_t>`) and a conversion operator (e.g. `operator struct sockaddr *()` whilst also exposing the container length. there are other attributes of an addrinfo you likely want to keep as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right. but I'm not sure if the cast between `uint8_t*` from vector to `sockaddr*` will be UB-free.

Comment: Sure. if that is a concern (I can only see it being as such for ip6 addrs, as dynamic alignment is guaranteed for all native types, including the largest, which is usually a long double), you can still do the above, but manage it via unique_ptr with proper alignment mechanics , or if you're really nuts, return to vector but use a custom allocator with custom maximal alignment. Regardless, I think you're ultimately going to need more than just the addr; you'll need the family, the proto, the length, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems valid to me. If you want to avoid dynamic allocations, you could also limit yourself to a union of all supported address families. Something like this:

```
union NetworkAddress
{
    sockaddr addr;
    sockaddr_in in4;
    sockaddr_in6 in6;

    static NetworkAddress from_addrinfo(const addrinfo* addr)
    {
        NetworkAddress rtrn;
        if(addr->ai_addrlen <= sizeof(rtrn))
            std::memcpy(&rtrn, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported network address");
        return rtrn;
    }
};
```

### Alternative: C++ Variant

If you compile for C++17, you could make use of std::variant. Personally, I don't see a big advantage. The sockaddr struct already contains a type tag which you now duplicate.

It is also more painful to use since most C interfaces expect a sockaddr pointer and not the specialized type so you have to do explicit casts.

It also results in less efficient code. For example GCC's implementation of std::visit results in indirect calls for what could be a simple if-else.

Here is an extended case study on how to implement `connect` with both approaches. Pick what you like best:

Option 1, the union:

```
union NetworkAddress
{
    sockaddr addr;
    sockaddr_in in4;
    sockaddr_in6 in6;

    static NetworkAddress from_addrinfo(const addrinfo* addr)
    {
        switch(addr->ai_family) {
        case AF_INET: break;
        case AF_INET6: break;
        default: throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported network address");
        }
        NetworkAddress rtrn;
        if(addr->ai_addrlen <= sizeof(rtrn))
            std::memcpy(&rtrn, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported network address");
        return rtrn;
    }
    std::size_t addrlen() const noexcept
    {
        switch(addr.sa_family) {
        case AF_INET: return sizeof(in4);
        case AF_INET6: return sizeof(in6);
        default: return 0; /* fail safe in later call */
        }
    }
    int connect(int socket) const noexcept
    { return ::connect(socket, &addr, addrlen()); }
};
```

Option 2, variant:

```
struct NetworkAddress2
{
    using addr_variant = std::variant<sockaddr_in, sockaddr_in6>;
    addr_variant addr;

    explicit NetworkAddress2(const addrinfo* addr)
    {
        switch(addr->ai_family) {
        case AF_INET:
            this->addr = reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr_in&>(*addr);
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            this->addr = reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr_in6&>(*addr);
            break;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported network address");
        }
    }
    std::size_t addrlen() const noexcept
    {
        switch(addr.index()) {
        case 0: return sizeof(sockaddr_in);
        case 1: return sizeof(sockaddr_in6);
        default: return 0;
        }
    }
    int connect(int socket) const
    {
#     if __cpp_generic_lambdas >= 201707L
        /* C++20: Use templated lambda */
        return std::visit([socket]<class T>(const T& addr) noexcept -> int {
            return ::connect(socket,
                             reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&addr),
                             sizeof(T));
        }, addr);
#     else
        const sockaddr* ptr;
        switch(addr.index()) {
        case 0:
            ptr = reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&std::get<0>(addr));
            break;
        case 1:
            ptr = reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&std::get<1>(addr));
            break;
        default:
            throw std::bad_variant_access{};
        }
        return ::connect(socket, ptr, addrlen());
#     endif
    }
};
```

Comment: If I wanted to try something like this, I would probably use `std::variant`. better approach because you will need size of structure too.

Comment: @Afshin I've extended the answer to cover that alternative. I don't think it is worth it. Especially before C++20 it is rather cumbersome to access the variant when all we really want is a sockaddr pointer and the size which can be deduced from the sa_family member. But maybe there is a more clever implementation

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use `boost::asio` (and use [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io) to install it).

```
// create address from string
auto someaddress=boost::asio::make_address("127.0.0.1");

// make a copy
boost::asio::ip::address copy=someaddress;
```